# How to solve 0x000012d error on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, freeze, google-chrome-extensions

Opening chrome, I often get the error "The aplication failed to initialize properly" 0x000012d error.Reinstallation didn't help. I've also reset my OS Windows 10, but after a few days, it gave the same error.

Sometimes, I also get the error: The laptop often says "low in memory". You need to restart all your programs.  and then it hangs.

Comment: Are your memory chips soldered on, or on removable modules?  If they are removable, it may help to reinsert them, to break any oxidation layer that has been forming on the contacts and interfering with communication.

Comment: They are soldered. The error occurs only on Windows 10 but not on Linux 16.04, dual booted.

Comment: Run a malware scan.  If you are running low on memory more often than you used to, it means something started using more.

Comment: I've tried it. Do you know what is 0x000012d error, exactly?

Comment: If it's coming from Windows, it is [Invalid Oplock Protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx)  Opportunistic locks are used when more than one program might try to access the same database file, to keep them from interfering with each other.  Check and make sure that no copies of Chrome are already running (check Task Manager details tab for `chrome.exe`), because nothing except Chrome itself should ever lock Chrome data files.

Comment: You can also try running Sysinternals Process Monitor (it's a download from Microsoft Technet) to try to find out exactly what file can't be locked.

Comment: Yes, there are certain copies of Chrome, though I cannot find them. I can tell for sure because, suddenly the Chrome occasionally shuts down and on restart it is all new with no previous data stored .

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

On Win 10 Home, I am not sure which of my attempts worked,

- but I ran SFC /scannow,
- then ran some of the DISM commands, as administrator,
- then shut everything down, cleaned out dust and dirt from inside the computer, fans & heatsinks,(because maybe it was running too hot),
- then took out the memory chips to clean the contacts and set them back in, CAREFULLY.
- Next I thought of the size of the virtual memory, in the pagefile, and after much searching I found where that was hidden, and I tripled the size of all its parameters.
- I also stopped Malwarebytes from running concurrently with Avast Security.

After all that, the low memory problem, instability and crashing disappeared.
So, I must have done something right. As I like to say: I am not always wrong! It's a low standard, but you gotta start somewhere.

Comment: Running two antivirus packages together is always going to knacker your speed.  It is a schoolboy error.